# Selenium exception handling, problems

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have problems with Java Selenium. I use it to automate testing web page, which structure is very complicated - a lot of elements are loaded dynamically, there is a lot of unnecessary elements in html pages. It's very difficult to make my tests reliable. Sometimes page can't load or I try to click on the button which doesn't exist yet (in similiar method of course).

So, I wrote Util class with methods like this one:

```
public static void findAndSendKeys(String vToSet, By vLocator) {
    log.info("findAndSendKeys " + vLocator.toString());
    int attempts = 0;
    while (attempts < ATTEMPTS) {
        WebElement element = null;
        try {

            element = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(vLocator));
            element.sendKeys(vToSet);
            break;

        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            log.error("timeOut exception " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            log.error("StaleElementReference exception " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnhandledAlertException e) {
            log.error("UnhandledAlert exception " + e.getMessage());
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();
        }
        attempts++;
    }
}
```

I know it looks terrible, I didn't refactor it yet, but method usually works fine for most cases - on the second or third loop input field is filled.

Firstly I was using only sendKeys with exception handling, but I noticed that although input field exists, StaleElementReferenceException is thrown, so I put while() in this static method and try to sendKeys again. 
Sometimes my webPage shows Alert that is just validation and after catching exception and ignoring alert I can continue work.

I wonder.. It could be easier if there would exist method similiar to "Pause 1000" method in Selenium IDE. Sometimes my web page works fast and good, sometimes page loading process is very long and I have to wait.

There is also problems with while() loop. I don't know what to do if while loop ends and nothing is send - for example loaded page/container is blank, dynamic loading fails, so there is no chance to find our input field

Automate testing process for this web page causes me a headache. Please, be placable, I don't have technical support and I am on my own.

Comment: Have you tried `.visibilityOfElementLocated()` instead of `presenceOfElementLocated()`? You might be running into issues where the element is in the DOM (presence) but not visible/clickable/sendKeys-toable.

Comment: @JeffC the problem is when I try f.e. to click on table row to sort elements ascending/descending and I get value of first elements in three ways:
1. before elements loaded  (they are not sorted)
2. during sorting, when elements are not visible
3. after sorting

The option that interests me is of course option 3. I tried presentsOfElementLocated, but It also causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are trying to overengineer the whole thing. I think you are trying to write a single function that will handle all cases and I don't think that is a good approach. Each case is potentially different and you will need to understand each case and handle it appropriately.

A few tips.

1. Don't loop a `wait.until()`. Instead of

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
       wait.until(...);
   }
   ```

   do

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
   wait.until(...);
   ```

   The end result is the same (max 50s wait) but the 2nd code is less confusing. Read up on waits to better understand them. The default behavior for a wait is to wait up to the max time and poll the condition every 500ms.
2. If you are getting `StaleElementReferenceException`, you are missing something. I don't mean that to sound critical... it happens. You need to understand how the HTML of the page is changing because you are looking for an element that is disappearing and *then* you try to scrape it. You will need to change either the element you are looking for or when you are looking for it.
3. Don't use `Thread.sleep()`. In general it's a bad practice because it's hard coded. Depending on the environment, it may be too long or not long enough of a wait. Instead prefer the `wait.until()` mechanism you are already using. The hard part, at times, is finding what to wait for.

If you are trying to scrape the page after the items are sorted, then you need to determine what changes after sorting occurs. Maybe there's an arrow on the column header that appears to indicate a sort direction (ascending vs descending)? One thing you could do is to grab one of the TD elements, wait for it to go stale (while the elements are being sorted), and then regrab all elements?

Maybe something like this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
// grab the first TD as a stale reference
WebElement td = driver.findElement(By.tagName("td"));
// wait for it to go stale
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(td));
// now grab them all and do something with them
List<WebElement> tds = driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

Without a link to the page or a lot more explanation of what is happening on the page and some relevant HTML, I'm not sure what else we can provide.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
jsPageLoadWait ="
try {
  if (document.readyState !== 'complete') {
    return false; // Page not loaded yet
  }
  if (window.jQuery) {
    if (window.jQuery.active) {
      return false;
    } else if (window.jQuery.ajax && window.jQuery.ajax.active) {
      return false;
    } else if ($(':animated').length != 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (window.angular) {
    if (!window.qa) {
      // Used to track the render cycle finish after loading is complete
      window.qa = {
        doneRendering: false
      };
    }
    // Get the angular injector for this app (change element if necessary)
    var injector = window.angular.element('body').injector();
    // Store providers to use for these checks
    var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
    var $http = injector.get('$http');
    var $timeout = injector.get('$timeout');
    // Check if digest
    if ($rootScope.$$phase === '$apply' || $rootScope.$$phase === '$digest' || $http.pendingRequests.length !== 0) {
      window.qa.doneRendering = false;
      return false; // Angular digesting or loading data
    }
    if (!window.qa.doneRendering) {
      // Set timeout to mark angular rendering as finished
      $timeout(function() {
        window.qa.doneRendering = true;
      }, 0);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
} catch (ex) {
  return false;
}"



public static Boolean WaitLoad(this ISearchContext context, UInt32 timeoutInMilliseconds = 10000, UInt32 millisecondPolling = 1000)
{
  Boolean waitReadyStateComplete;

  var wait = new DefaultWait<ISearchContext>(context);
  wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutInMilliseconds);
  wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecondPolling);
  wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));

  waitReadyStateComplete = wait.Until<Boolean>(ctx =>
  {
    if ((Boolean)((IJavaScriptExecutor)context).ExecuteScript(jsPageLoadWait))
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  });

  return waitReadyStateComplete;
}
```